# VBA SQL Connection to Excel from Word returns no records

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ado, recordset

I'm having fits trying to figure out how to read records from an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document.   I'm using Office 365.  I found a few articles that have gotten me connected to the workbook and sheet but no records are returned. 
I referenced the ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
When the code gets to the message box it returns a -1

Help?  What am I missing?

Here is what I have for code at this point.

```
Sub CreateLetter()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, rsCount As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlGetTbl As String
Dim sDataSource As String, sDataTable As String
Dim sProvider As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sDataSource = "D:\spreadsheetname.xlsx"
sDataTable = "[Donor Contact List$]"

sProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;"
sDataSource = sDataSource & ";Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes';"

With cn
    .Provider = sProvider
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sDataSource
    .Open
End  With

sqlGetTbl = "SELECT * FROM " & sDataTable
Set rs = cn.Execute(sqlGetTbl)
MsgBox rs.RecordCount

Do
    With Selection
        .TypeText FullName & Chr(11) & Street & Chr(11) & City & ", " & St & "  " & Zip
        .TypeParagraph
    End With
Loop Until rs.EOF

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Try `cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient`. If this doesn't work, use `Recordset` (again with `CursorLocation = adUseClient`) instead of `Connection`.

Comment: to clarify - spreadsheets like Excel have *cells and rows* (not records). Database tables (like Access) have *records*. Regardless, there are easier ways of getting data into Word - unless there's a reason you need to do it like this.  I'd suggest starting with searching Google for "import data from Excel into Word."  There are several ways to do so depending on the end-goal.

Comment: @ashleedawg It's quite possible to connect to Excel as a data source, using ADO, DAO or ODBC. In this case, one does use the data source terminology, records and fields. Using a data connection generally has less overhead and is faster than "automation" since the file is accessed directly with no need to load it in the Excel application; as a matter of fact, it can be used even if Excel is not installed on the machine. The approach the OP proposes is quite valid and even to be recommended...

Comment: @WinginSue Is there any reason for not using mailmerge? No code required.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. The key to getting the recordset information in the test data source I used was including `IMEX=1` in the connection string in order to specify that the data source has headers.

The code in the question has additional problems:

1. It's necessary to use `rs.MoveFirst` to "initialize" the recordset (get it to the first record.
2. It's necessary to use `rs.MoveNext` in each iteration of the loop, otherwise the code will "get stuck" on the first record and go into an infinite loop.
3. It's safer to use `Do While Not rs.EOF` for the test for exiting the loop in case there really are no records in the recordset.
4. It's necessary to specify the *fields* from the recordset. Fullname, city, street, etc. are meaningless, at least in the code in the question.
5. Always release objects (set to `Nothing`) in the reverse order they were created. It's not possible to release the connection before the recordset is released - the active recordset will keep the connection "live".

My sample code:

```
Sub CreateLetter()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, rsCount As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sqlGetTbl As String
    Dim sDataSource As String, sDataTable As String
    Dim sProvider As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sDataSource = "D:\spreadsheetname.xlsx"
    sDataTable = "[Donor Contact List$]"

    sProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;"
    sDataSource = sDataSource & ";Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

    With cn
        .Provider = sProvider
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sDataSource
        .Open
    End With

    sqlGetTbl = "SELECT * FROM " & sDataTable
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sqlGetTbl)
    MsgBox rs.RecordCount
    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        With Selection
            .TypeText rs.Fields("Fullname").value & Chr(11) & rs.Fields("street").value & Chr(11) & rs.Fields("city").value & ", " & st & "  " & rs.Fields("Zip").Value
            .TypeParagraph
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: *IMEX=True* You probably meant `HDR=Yes`? 

Comment: @JohnyL No, I meant IMEX - the original code already contains `HDR`. However, it was quite late and I ended up typing "True" instead of "1". Thanks for pointing it out!